# how to check if the 2D array is sorted from greatest to lowest

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, for-loop

If I have a 2d array like this

```
  int[,] arr = { { 0, 1, 4 }, { 3, 9, 5 }, { 6, 8, 2 } };
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(arr[i, j] + " ");

            }
            Console.WriteLine();

        }
```

result:

```
0 1 4
3 9 5 
6 8 2
```

I want to check if it is sorter from highest to lowest like `8` to `0` I was thinking maybe a bool type to check if it is true or not, but I dont really know if that would work

Comment: Are you wanting it to return true only if each subsequent 1D array is sorted? ex:

[9 6 0]
[8 5 2]
[4 1 3]

Comment: Do you want to check it for every separate row or for the entire array?

Comment: Is this homework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert two-dimensional array into one-dimensional using [`Cast`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.cast?view=netframework-4.8) method. Then ensure that every next item is less or equal than previous, otherwise array isn't sorted by descending

```cs
int[,] arr = { { 0, 1, 4 }, { 3, 9, 5 }, { 6, 8, 2 } };
var flatten = arr.Cast<int>().ToList();
var isSorted = true;
for (int i = 0; i < flatten.Count() - 1; i++)
{
    if (flatten[i] <= flatten[i + 1])
    {
        isSorted = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

You can also check that array is sorted by descending using [`Zip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=netframework-4.8) method

```cs
var flatten = arr.Cast<int>();
var isSorted = flatten.Zip(flatten.Skip(1), (current, next) => current >= next).All(x => x);
```

Comment: hm I checked the first code when I have the array 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 it doesn't break

Comment: @zellez it shouldn't break, because array is sorted by descending already and meet your criteria. It should break only when array is not sorted and set `isSorted = false;` Before loop we assuming that array is sorted and `isSorted = true`

Comment: When I run it `isSorted = true` is true with `8 7 6 5 4 3 0 1 2` and `8 7 6 5 4 3 2 0 1` and doesnt change to false

Comment: @zellez It does, just checked `{ 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 0, 1 }` sample and it sets `isSorted` to `false` at last loop iteration. `Zip` method gives the same result, please double check your data

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check if the entire array is sorted, you could do using Linq as

```
var flattedList = arr.OfType<int>().ToList();
var result = flattedList.OrderByDescending(x=>x).SequenceEqual(flattedList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perform a sort/check on each subsequent 1D array. With that, you can check if either x, y, or both are sorted to how you want. Some sorting algorithms have a way to let you know if they are sorted built in.